# How to handle inefficiency of Django's Queryset?

Tags: python, django, database

I've seen other questions, but unfortunately i couldn't find similar problems yet.

The size of information is approximately equal to 1 GB, but the amount of objects that i'm iterating through is very big. (I'm unable to find it out though, shell is automatically killed in minutes after i execute `len(model.objects.all())`.

Considering that the process is killed just by trying to get its length (by utilizing `len` function, I also tried `count()` method, but it seems to be limited to certain extent), I knew searching through the objects would be negligible (especially searching through them by utilizing similarity algorithms).

But i still tried it, I've used [Cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) to find out the best match, this is the code for search:

```
zsim = ("", 0)
for qst in Question.objects.all().iterator():
    sim = cosine_similarity(qst.question, string)
    if zenith_sim[1] > 0.75:
        break
    elif sim > zenith_sim[1]:
        zenith_sim = (qst.answer, sim)
return str(zenith_sim[0])
```

The code above searches for the string that is most similar to the string of the user, although to avoid insignificant iteration, if the similarity is above 75%, it breaks the loop. I've also used `iterator()` method hoping that it would save some memory.

As expected, the process was killed few minutes later after its execution. I'm not sure how can this be improved. The machine itself is not slow, although it can not be classified as supercomputer.

---

Systems of large organizations can execute similarity query through the information of 100+ petabytes in seconds.

I wonder what could be used to increase efficiency of similarity query, searching through this data causes Django to kill its own process. What could be the solution for efficient query? Is direct database search much more efficient?

Comment: "Systems of large organizations" use specialised databases that can filter petabytes of data. They don't use sqlite or even postgres, they use things like Google BigQuery that are optimised for this. And what's more they *let the database do the work*, they absolutely definitely don't try and load everything into application code and do comparisons there.

Comment: Looping against the queryset is very painful there is no caching into it. Please refer to this documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#caching-and-querysets

Comment: So what could be the most efficient method for searching for similarities through databases? Will iteration directly through database make any significant sifference? I've heard that PostgreSQL has custom implementation of Levenshtein distance, is it much more efficient?

Comment: the best way would be to use db level tools and functions to handle this for you, not iterating through each thing in django.

Answer (score 1):

(Pardon  me if i don't quite understand correctly what you are trying to do)
Did you try this to count data returned ?

```
model.objects.all().count()
```

Also, why not use  model.objects.filter() to limit amount of data retreived ?

Maybe you should be using the [django debug toolbar](https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar) to debug the bottlenecks in those queries.

Comment: I tried this right now, but as i see the `count` method is limited to certain extent? I've tried obtaining length with while loop until incrementing variable until receiving `IndexError`, but i stopped it at some point (it took too much time) and the variable was more than eight digits, but whenever i tried Django's count method it outputted integer of 7 digits (4941474).

Comment: Also i'm not using filter method since i'm executing a similarity search, Thus i'm not only looking for identical values, but similar values as well.

Comment: 4941474 should be the total  rows in the table (since you are doing .all() ). Can you verify this ? About the index error - if this table has foreign key relation to a parent table, maybe a row in this table is still pointing to the id of a deleted row in the parent table ( very unlikely though ).